# Gravity forms not working in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I am new to Gravity forms. I have installed the premium plugin in my Wordpress website, but nothing is working.

When I create New Form -> Title, Description -> Select the Standard Fields -> Below Point 1 is coming and the circle keeps revolving, revolving and nothing happens..

and Second, the update form button is not working (as shown in point 2)

1) `http://s12.postimg.org/uor99gkel/image.jpg` 
2) `http://s11.postimg.org/tzydo602r/image.jpg`

I have tried everything to make it work, I tried Google, Youtube tutorials, documentations, etc. But nothing works, Any help will be really great help..

Thanks

I have WordPress 4.4.2 running HQE theme.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a plugin or theme conflict. The best thing to do is disable all other plugins except gravity forms and test it again. If it's working then reactivate your other plugins one by one and test after you activate each one until you find the culprit.

If after deactivating all other plugins it still doesn't work then you should activate one of the default Wordpress themes such as 2015 and test gravity forms again.

Comment: Still the same problem, i deactivated all the plugins and activate 2015 theme. still same problem

Comment: If that didn't work I would uninstall and re-install gravity forms. Also double check that you have the most recent version. If none of that helps I would submit a support ticket at gravity forms.